# duplicate values in a selectbox html/php

Tags: php

I have an update page with a select box which is filled by PHP...how can I hide the duplicate values?

this is my code;

Corrective action:

```
<label id="required">*</label><br>
<select name="correctiemaatregelen" class="form-control" id="correctiemaatregelen" style="width: 300px" required>
    <?php while ($row27 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result27)):; ?>
        <option selected value="<?php echo $row27['correctie_maatregelen'];?>"><?php echo $row27['correctie_maatregelen'];?></option>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    <?php while ($row28 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result28)):; ?>
        <option selected value="<?php echo $row28['correctie_maatregelen_select'];?>"><?php echo $row28['correctie_maatregelen_select'];?></option>
    <?php endwhile;?>
</select>
```

[Selectbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDuyE.png)

Sorry if my English is horrible

Comment: Remove the semi-colons in the loops; they end the statements. You should be getting errors here for the endwhile's.

Comment: This also appears to be a repost of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53276580/how-to-echo-php-and-html-in-if-statement).

Comment: You have too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this php snippet:-

```
$options = array();
while ($row27 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result27)){
    $options[] = $row27['correctie_maatregelen'];
}
while ($row28 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result28)){
    $options[] = $row28['correctie_maatregelen_select'];
}
$options = array_unique($options);
```

And for the rendering options, you can use foreach loop.

```
<label id="required">*</label><br>
<select name="correctiemaatregelen" class="form-control" id="correctiemaatregelen" style="width: 300px" required>
    <?php foreach($options as $color): ?>
        <option selected value="<?php echo $color;?>"><?php echo $color;?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

Comment: why don't you explain why their code failed?

Comment: also, the `foreach` won't work. You did the same error they did in the `while` loops.

Comment: Answer Edited..